# Increase input[] array number with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following inputs in my HTMl form:

```
<input type='text' name='speaker[][]' class='form-control mb5' placeholder='Speaker' value='' />
<input type='text' name='seminartitle[][]' class='form-control mb5' placeholder='Seminar Title' value='' />
```

Now, I have a button elsewhere on the form that duplicates the row that these inputs are contained in.  What i'd like to be able to do is replace the first `[]` with a number, so on the first row i'd have:

```
<input type='text' name='speaker[0][]' class='form-control mb5' placeholder='Speaker' value='' />
<input type='text' name='seminartitle[0][]' class='form-control mb5' placeholder='Seminar Title' value='' />
```

And on the second:

```
<input type='text' name='speaker[1][]' class='form-control mb5' placeholder='Speaker' value='' />
<input type='text' name='seminartitle[1][]' class='form-control mb5' placeholder='Seminar Title' value='' />
```

And so on.  I don't know how to go about doing this in javascript/jquery.

Comment: Could you share the code you use to duplicate the inputs?

Comment: @GMchris its just `$.clone();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've cloned the input you can extract it's `name` attribute like so. (Assuming you've saved the input in a variable called $clonedInput)

`var speakerName = $clonedInput.attr('name');`

Then use a regular expression (RegEx) to determine if it already has some content and if it doesn't assign it a 0.

```
var speakerIndex = speakerName.match(\[(\d)?\]\[\]);
speakerIndex = parseInt(speakerIndex[1]);
speakerIndex = isNaN(speakerIndex) ? 0 : speakerIndex + 1;
```

Finally we change the attribute of our cloned element.

`$clonedInput.attr('name', 'speaker[' + speakerIndex + '][]';`

Some clarification:

The RegEx is checking to find the following pattern `[<optional number>][]`, meaning that you can use the same RegEx for both `input`s since it doesn't check to see if it's the `speaker` or `seminartitle`. The reason we're accessing `speakerIndex[1]` is that the regex has a capture group around the hypothetical number.

Comment: Thank you, while I didnt actually use the regex you gave me, I did use the method of extracting the name and then replacing it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your number by replacing the current name value by the result of this function:

```
function addNumber(num, inputName, position){
    if(inputName !== "speaker[][]"){
        return null;
    }else{
        var res = [inputName.slice(0, position), num, inputName.slice(position)].join('');
        return res;
    }
}
```

with num : the number you want to put
inputName : the input name of the input you want to change
the position : the position where you want to put the num in the inputName.

You just have to replaced le name of the input by the returned value of the function.